# Chart with time on X-axis and value on Y-axis with hyperlinks

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, highcharts

I'm looking for a free library (something on the lines of highcharts or d3.js) where i'm looking to plot months of an year for the next 5 years on the X-axis and a quantity on the Y-axis. I would like to add hyperlinks to the Y-axis value and add references to the sources for my data. I was looking through d3.js and couldn't find anything like this but the collection is huge, maybe I missed it. Any suggestions on what I should use?

Comment: Start reading the D3 docs and you might find the solution after a while. SO is not a programming service.

Comment: I couldn't find anything/any resource where I could add hyperlinks. I don't know why I got a negative vote. It is completely within guidelines to ask a technical question which is not properly documented.

Comment: maybe `svgelem.on('click', callback);`

Comment: Please tell me what you mean saying `I would like to add hyperlinks to the Y-axis value and add references to the sources for my data.`? Do you need to add this hyperlinks when clicking on points, yAxis labels or somewhere in the tooltip maybe?

Comment: Either of them will work, if you can point me to one, I can maybe work on the others. The point being i'd like for users to be able to click on either points or tooltips as long as there is a hyper link associated with the Y-axis value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a `subtitle` of your chart, and define there a link to your data source, and also do the same in your `tooltip.pointFormat` definition. Here is the code:

```
subtitle: {
    useHTML: true,
    text: 'Data source: <a href="google.com">somewhereinthenet.com</a>'
},
tooltip: {
    useHTML: true,
    style: {
        pointerEvents: 'auto'
    },
    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b><br/><span style="font-size: 10px">Data source: <a href="google.com" class="tooltip-link">somewhereinthenet.com</a>'
}
```

**Live example:** https://jsfiddle.net/3tkx75uq/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/subtitle

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.pointFormat

Comment: Thanks! SO needs more members like you who actually help.